# ¿Como mostrar un EditorFor en base a un elemento seleccionado de un DropDownList en MVC 5?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, dropdownlist

Saludos tengo la siguiente situación.

Tengo el siguiente código en una vista

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdDestinoPersona, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("IdDestinoPersona", null, "SELECCIONE UN DESTINO", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdDestinoPersona, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Destino, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Destino, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",  id = "destinoAlternativo" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Destino, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Solo necesito que el EditorFor se active cuando el DropDownList se seleccione la opción "SELECCIONE UN DESTINO" y cuando se seleccione un destino real del DropDownList se desactive el EditorFor.

¿Me podrian ayudar a solventar esta situación?, ¿Existe alguna forma de hacerlo con JQuery?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este script the debería de ayudar. La idea es captar el evento de 'change' y agregar o remover el atributo de 'disable' de acuerdo a la acción.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#IdDestinoPersona').on('change', function () {
            if ($('#IdDestinoPersona').val() == '') {
                alert('remove');
                $('#destinoAlternativo').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                alert('add');
                $('#destinoAlternativo').attr("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```